# What do you call a "Questions & Answers site" (Q&A) in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I am looking for a German term to describe StackExchange - the English term seems to be "Questions & Answers site" (Q&A) which has no equivalent in German (that I'm aware of). The literal translation "Frage-und-Antwort-Webseite" sounds too complicated to me as a native German speaker, there must be a better term instead of "Frage und Antwort". Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: For me (also native speaker)  _Frage und Antwort_ sounds ok, only _Webseite_ sounds ugly. I would use _Frage und Antwort Seite(n)_ or the denglisch _"Frage und Antwort-Site_.

Comment: Most people would prefer "Netzwerk" or "Community" above "Seite", as "Seite" sounds very crude in this context.

Comment: Was an Frage & Antwort ist komplizierter als question & answer? Wieso **muss** es etwas einfacheres geben? Wo ist dieser Zwang verortet - ist es ein Naturgesetz, eine juristisch fixierte Sache?

Comment: @userunknown: Im Deutschen werden Komposita bevorzugt, so dass "Frage und Antwort" weniger als ein Objekt wahrgenommen wird. Im Englischen sind unverbundene Kombinationen mehrerer Wörter dagegen üblich.

Comment: Schnee und Eis, Kaffee und Kuchen, "Ton, Steine, Scherben", dumm und dümmer - so ungewöhnlich als dass sie eine Schwierigkeit wären sind Konjunktionen und Aufzählungen auch nicht. Die Behauptung war aber auch gar nicht dass das eine häufiger ist, sondern dass es komplizierter ist. Inwiefern ist es kompliziert?

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn ich Jakob richtig verstehe, geht es ihm nicht um "Frage & Antwort", sondern um "Frage und Antwort Seite" und er findet dieses deutsche Ungetüm "holprig" bzw. "sperrig" - und ich stimme dem zu. Wenn überhaupt, müsste es ja wohl "Frage- und Antwort-Seite" heißen und es klingt einfach nicht gut. In ein paar Jahren sieht das bestimmt schon wieder anders aus - die Macht der Gewohnheit hat ja bei "Schnee und Eis", "Kaffee und Kuchen" und "Ton, Steine, Scherben" auch funktioniert... (+1 für das schrillste Beispiel des Tages) :)

Comment: Dass es um eine Frage/Antwort-Seite geht habe ich durchaus mitbekommen; allein es ist weder in irgendeiner bekannten Hinsicht kompliziert. Noch ein Wortungetüm, mit dem man ein Grundschulkind erschrecken könnte. `Frage` und `Antwort` sind mit die einfachsten Begriffe die man sich denken kann - `Seite` als Webpräsenz ist etwas schwieriger, aber ich sehe nicht, was daran auf Englisch auch nur einen Deut einfacher sein soll. Holprig und Sperrig ein Begriffspaar zu nennen, das aus 2silbigen Wörtern besteht - ich weiß ja auch nicht auf welches Niveau wir runter sollen - grunzen?

Comment: Ich behaupte mal, dass es bei einer Mehrheit aller Deutschen EXTREM holprig und sperrig klingt, wenn sie es mal laut lesen oder sagen müssen. Frage und Antwort ist dann auf einmal nicht mehr ganz so scheiße.

Comment: @Mac Wenn schon "Frage- und Antwortseite", was es aber auch nicht besser macht ;)

Comment: Dann nenn es "Frage-Antwortseite", oder "Selbsthilfeseite". Oder "lol", das ist wirklich einfach. Sagen wir zu allem nur noch "lol" - alles andere ist holprig, kompliziert und ein Ungetüm.

Comment: @Em1 Noch richtiger wäre aber Frage-und-Antwort-Seite, da es sich nicht ume eine Frage seite zuzüglich einer Antwortseit ehandelt.

Comment: @user unknown, da kann ich Dir nur zu[schlumpfen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Schl%C3%BCmpfe#Sprache_der_Schl%C3%BCmpfe)!

Answer (score 14):

Looking at the larger German Q&A sites and what they are calling themselves, there appears to be no standardized term for it:

- gutefrage.net: Die Ratgeber-Community
- wer-weiss-was.de: Know-How-Netzwerk

I would simply revert to *"Frage-Antwort-Seite"* / *"Frage-Antwort-Forum"* since this is closest to the English Q&A original.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Note that there is no simple abbreviation such as the English "Q&A".

Comment: @Jakob: Note that there has been a software called Q&A, which was sold as F&A in Germany.

Comment: Das Wort *Seite* in Frage-Antwort-Seite stört mich ein wenig, da es sich ja nicht um eine *Seite*, sondern eine *Site* handelt.

Comment: @splattne It sounded too Denglish for my ears, hence the "Seite". Especially since the two words are pronounced rather similarly and used in a similar context for the web: website - Webseite. I guess it would be understood, although I agree that it is not extraordinarily elegant.

Answer (score 6):

#### Frage-und-Antwort-Seiten

There is nothing wrong with using these idiomatic pair of expressions for an Internet Q & A site. It will be perfectly understood as we do use these expressions in other contexts too, e.g.:

> - [*"Frage-und-Antwort-Spiel"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Frage_und_Antwort_Spiel)
> - *"Frage und Anwort stehen"* as a newer derivate from the idiom *"Rede und Antwort stehen"*

In case we do not want to use this more or less literal translated form we may  reword it to something like:

> *"Stack Exchange bietet Internetseiten für Antworten auf Fragen."* - *"Die Internetseiten von SE beantworten ihre/deine Fragen."* - *"Für Antworten auf Fragen wird man auf den Stack-Exchange-Seiten fündig"*

Comment: *"Seite"* is a poor translation, it also understood as *"page"* and StackExchange is more dynamic. How about *"StackExchange ist ein Frage-und-Antwort-Netzwerk."* and *"Die Frage-und-Antwort-Community unter http://german.stackexchange.org beschäftigt sich mit der Deutschen Sprache"*?

Comment: I deliberately made it plural because of that and asked another question: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4871/is-an-internetseite-also-a-website ;)

Comment: Einfach "Seiten" in Mehrzahl zu verwenden ist wahrlich clever!

Comment: I've never heard "Frage und Antwort stehen" and it sounds *very* wrong to me. Of course that's just a subjective perception.

Comment: @celtschk: Sounds kind of strange to me too, but the similarity makes it easily recognizable. "Jemandem Rede und Antwort stehen" means to answer all questions, so it's already close, and it seems that "Jemandem Frage und Antwort stehen" is already in use as a derivate of the former, just like Takkat said.

Answer (score 4):

From time to time, for example in the [PM-Magazine](http://www.pm-magazin.de/m/pm-fragen-antworten/pm-fragen-antworten-%E2%80%93-woher-kommt-die-neue-sehnsucht-nach-zu-hause), I have seen the literal translation "**Fragen und Antworten**" - abbreviated "**F & A**". See the result of the [Google Search](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&gs_nf=1&cp=8&gs_id=53&xhr=t&q=Fragen+und+Antworten&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=Fragen+u&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5b0c526093921f78&biw=1920&bih=931) and the Wikipedia article on [Frequently Asked Questions](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions).

As it seems like "**F & A**" is not used very often (yet), I would say "**Website mit Fragen und Antworten zu ...**" - or join the Avantgarde and use "**F & A-Website**".

Answer (score 3):

I particularly like the "Community" cited by syneticon-dj, but I don't consider "Frage und Antwort" bad; however one might omit the "und" here. Therefore my suggestion:

**Frage-Antwort-Community**

Answer (score 0):

I remember that a while ago I contributed to the German Wikipedia article "[Digitale Auskunft](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitale_Auskunft)" which described a more general concept. "Auskunft" may be a good translation of "Frage und Antwort", as well as "Ratgeber" or the composition "Frage-Antwort" suggested by syneticon-dj. How about "Kollaborativer Auskunftsdienst"?

**Edit:** As suggested by Mr. Beast and syneticon-dj, "Netzwerk" or "Community" fit well. "Auskunft" instead of "Frage und Antwort" is a known and simple term but its connotation is somehow against the collaborative nature of most Q&A sites. So the best I could find by now is "Auskunftsnetzwerk" or "Auskunftscommunity".

Comment: I don't think "Auskunft" matches the intent of SE very well. "Auskunft" suggests the very thing SE wants to avoid: People coming here to ask a question, and not caring any more after the answer has arrived.

Comment: @celtschk: Hmmm, true, but so does Q&A, strictly speaking, doesn't it? I think the "-dienst" part is much more of a problem here: it sounds quite literally like a service hotline or something...

Comment: Do you seriously discard Frage und Antwort as too complicated just to suggest "Kollaborativer Auskunftsdienst" as an alternative for the common man... a well earned -1

Comment: @Mac: I don't think "Q&A" does suggest it in the same way, because unlike "Auskunft" it doesn't tell on which side the visitor is (you wouldn't expect to go to an "Auskunft" in order to answer questions, only in order to ask them).

Comment: @celtschk: True, good point!

Answer (score -2):

You can Use Q&A as well for German sites, everybody will know what it means, even though it's English.

Or you could use the German translation

> Frage- und Antwortseite

Comment: Meine Eltern sind Deutsche und wissen mit Sicherheit nicht, was Q&A sein soll.

Comment: @user unknown Es kommt natürlich drauf an, an wen sich die Seite richtet. Bei einem Forum für rüstige Senioren würde ich wohl auch nicht Q&A benutzen, bei einem Forum für angehende Informatiker zum Beispiel wäre der Begriff sicher nicht übertrieben, und jeder versteht was gemeint ist.

Comment: Ich wüsste nicht dass rüstige Rentner vom Besuch abgehalten werden sollen - jedenfalls sind sie mit "everybody" inkludiert - es läge also an Dir präziser zu formulieren wenn nur Teenager und Twens gemeint sind.

Comment: @user unknown Wenn jemand eine Website betreibt, hat er immer eine oder mehrere bestimmte Zielgruppen im visier, und es ist doch klar dass nicht jede man mit allen Zielgruppen verschieden umgehen muss.
Mit meiner Antwort wollte ich lediglich drauf hindeuten, dass eine Mehrheit der Internetbesucher Q&A verstehen wird...was ist daran das problem

Comment: "Mehrheit" ist "majority", "everybody" ist "jeder". Vielleicht solltest Du auf Deutsch antworten wenn Dein Englisch nicht so weit trägt.

Comment: @userunknown meine englischen fähigkeiten bereiten mir keine probleme, und in welcher sprache ich zu antworten habe steht alleine in meiner entscheidungsgewalt. mein ziel war es eigentlich nicht diese geschichte auf die persönliche ebene runterzuringen, aber wenn es dein offensichtliches ziel ist, andere zu bemängeln, dann sind deine zerebralen fähigkeiten auf gewissen ebenen noch im frühen entwicklungsstadium. Probier doch mal als unterstützer zu agieren und nicht störfaktor. (ps: ich habe in diesem comment bewusst nicht auf die gross- kleinschreibung geachtet, musst du nicht extra erwähnen)