# Ist es "die" Webseite und "der" Link?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, expression

Ich habe all meine Computerkenntnis in den USA erlernt, und deshalb verstehe ich kaum, wie man technische Sachen nennt, und ob man *die*, *der* oder *das* sagt.

Könnte mir jemand helfen, die folgenden Begriffe zu erläutern?

Englisch:

- web page
- home page
- link
- web site
- cursor
- click (Drücken?)
- button (Knopf?)
- search field (Suchfeld?)
- icon
- URL

Falls es eine "Webpage" gibt, die all das erklärt, wäre ich ebenfalls für einen "Link" dankbar.

Comment: Schon mal an die Nutzung eines Onlinelexikons gedacht? Da die Fragen alle unabhängig voneinander sind ist die Auswahl der 'richtigen Antwort' eine schlecht lösbare Aufgabe. Sammelfragen sind hier m.W. off topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- web page = die Webseite
- home page = die Homepage
- link = der Link
- web site = hier wird im Deutschen nicht so stark unterschieden: Die "web site", die ja grundsätzlich den kompletten Webauftritt umfasst, wird im Deutschen ebenfalls "Homepage", "Webseite" oder auch "Website" genannt (siehe auch [Is an “Internetseite” also a website?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4871/1224))
- cursor = auch im Deutschen der Cursor
- click = der Klick, bzw. anklicken
- button (Knopf?) = der Button; auch die Schaltfläche (aber eher unüblich)
- search field (Suchfeld?) - ja! das Suchfeld
- icon = das Icon oder das Symbol
- URL = die URL oder die Internetadresse

Comment: Fehlt eigentlich nur noch ein Link zu http://dict.leo.org/ - dort sind alle diese Begriffe und noch viele mehr zu finden.

Comment: @Takkat Bloß nicht. Kein Link zu [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=home+page). Wieviele dieser Begriffe verwendest du für Homepage? - Besser wären Links zu [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Homepage) und Co. mit entsprechenden Definition und so.

Comment: @Em1: [Homepage](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=homepage) = *"die Homepage"* - erster Eintrag. Was soll daran schlecht sein? [Duden](http://www.duden.de/) ist natürlich auch gut, findet aber etwas weniger (vor allem, wenn es um Alternativen geht).

Comment: @Takkat Oups. Der erste Beitrag ist der naheliegenste (identisches Wort) und auch noch richtig. Aber noch mal: Wieviele dieser Begriffe verwendest du (im Kontext)? Nur eines? Ich auch. - Aber schlagen wir mal ein anderes Wort nach, [comfortable](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=comfortable). Zwar nicht der erste Eintrag, aber mittendrin steht *komfortabel*. Ist eine richtige Übersetzung, nicht wahr? Super, ich fühle mich nämlich total komfortabel heute. - Online dictionaries muss man mit viel Vorsicht genießen.

Comment: @Em1: heute bin ich eher *"kommod"* ;P

Comment: Ich glaube als Faustregel lässt sich sagen, dass bei IT-Begriffen eine Verwendung der Englischen Begriffe im Deutschen fast immer passt (auch wenn manche das als schlechten Stil empfinden). Einziger Unterschied: Nomen (nouns) werden dann groß geschrieben.

Comment: @mg_ Vielen Dank. Das war sehr nett von Dir!

Comment: @Em1 und Takkat: Das ist mir zu eng gesehen. *Jedes* Übersetzungswerk muss man mit Vorsicht genießen. Da unterscheidet sich Leo nicht von einem Papier-Langenscheidt.

Answer (score -1):

Der Artikel richtet sich auch bei Fremdsprachen entnommenen Wörtern in der Regel nach dem Geschlecht der deutschen Übersetzung (bei Komposita: des letzten Teils).

Daher:

1. *Die* Web-Seite (wegen "die Seite")
2. *Die* Homepage (wegen "die Page", wegen page = "die Seite")
3. *Der* Cursor (wegen cursor = "der Mauszeiger", wegen "der Zeiger")
4. *Der* Button (wegen button = "der Knopf")
5. *Der* URL (wegen URL = "Uniform Resource Locator", locator = "der Zeiger")

Anders als üblicherweise verwendet müsste es aber beispielsweise heißen *die Link* (wegen link = "die Verbindung") – außer man übersetzt link mit "der Verweis", dann ist es wieder *der Link*.

Comment: _Der_ URL wirst Du nur in fachsprachlichem Zusammenhang finden, sehr viel häufiger aber _die_ URL – und das dürfte so wegen URL=Verlinkung/Verbindung entstanden sein. Es müsste dann im Übrigen auch _der_ Website heißen wegen der Netzauftritt.

Comment: Mag sein, dass es umgangssprachlich als *die URL* verwendet wird (ich verwende es selbst häufig so, in dem Wissen, dass es eigentlich nicht stimmt) - aber URL ist *nicht* eine Verlinkung oder Verbindung, sondern eine absolute Ortsangabe (technisch betrachtet). Wenn man "Web Site" offiziell als "Netzauftritt" übersetzt, dann ja, heißt es "der WebSite". Du kannst *site* aber auch als "Stelle" übersetzen und schon stimmt *die WebSite*.

Comment: Die Geschlechter von Lehnwörtern richten sich nicht nach denen deutscher Entsprechungen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Nein? http://canoo.net/blog/2007/09/24/geschlecht-von-fremdwortern/? Oder hier: https://www.uni-due.de/~lge292/trainer/trainer/seiten/s524.html? Oder hier: http://faql.de/genus.html? Ich sagte ja nicht, dass es so festgeschrieben ist, sondern dass es in der Regel so gemacht wird.

Comment: Aus dem letzten der drei von Dir genannten Texte: „Oft wird beispielsweise behauptet, daß es die E-Mail sein müsse, weil es ja die Post sei. Hätte sich im Laufe der Zeit jedoch der oder das E-Mail als vorherrschend herauskristallisiert, hätten hinterher dieselben Schlauberger wahrscheinlich auf der Brief, das Schreiben oder ein anderes bedeutungsähnliches Nichtfremdwort mit selbem Genus verwiesen, das angeblich ganz klar Vorbild für die Genuswahl gewesen sein muß.“

Comment: Tja, dennoch wird diese Regel in vielen Fällen angewandt. Tut mir ja leid, wenn dir das nicht gefällt. Ich habe jedoch immer noch nicht behauptet, dass dies zwingend immer so ist. Genauso gut könntest du bei der akzeptierten Antwort nach Belegen fragen.